# How can I seed users and roles in my asp.net core 3.1 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, roles, asp.net-core-3.1

I tried using `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` in my IdentityDataContext class and creating a migration that will seed this data:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        const string ADMIN_ID = "b4280b6a-0613-4cbd-a9e6-f1701e926e73";
        const string ROLE_ID = ADMIN_ID;
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
        {
            Id = ROLE_ID,
            Name = "admin",
            NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
        });
        builder.Entity<MyIdentityUser>().HasData(new MyIdentityUser
        {
            Id = ADMIN_ID,
            UserName = "myemail@myemail.com",
            NormalizedUserName = "MYEMAIL@MYEMAIL.COM",
            Email = "myemail@myemail.com",
            NormalizedEmail = "MYEMAIL@MYEMAIL.COM",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            PasswordHash = "AQABBAEABCcQAABAEBhd37krE/TyMklt3SIf2Q3ITj/dunHYr7O5Z9UB0R1+dpDbcrHWuTBr8Uh5WR+JrQ==",
            SecurityStamp = "VVPCRDAS3MJWQD5CSW2GWPRADBXEZINA",
            ConcurrencyStamp = "c8554266-b401-4519-9aeb-a9283053fc58"
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            RoleId = ROLE_ID,
            UserId = ADMIN_ID
        });
    }
```

which seems to work, but I cannot access my endpoint in Razor Page decorated with Authorize atribute. It's strange because I have all this data in my database. I can log in as this user and I see that there is "admin" role in AspNetRoles table. I have also user mapped to role correctly in AspNetUserRoles table.

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        return Page();
    }

}
```

I'm being redirected to access denied page when logged as the user above which according to database has the admin role.

I saw that some people try to do this seed method in Configure method in Startup class, but I'm currently having trouble with dependency injection when i try to do this with RoleManager and UserManager:

`` System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered. ``

Comment: Would you share your startup.cs so i can try to reproduce it ?

Answer (score 8):

I was almost there.
It was not obvious at first, but I needed to add `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` line in my Configure method of IdentityHostingStartup.cs file.

It's mentioned at the end of Role-based authorization page from asp.net core 3.1 documentation:
[link to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

I thought that roles are already taken into consideration and I don't need to explicitly add this functinality.

It should be stated on top of the page that in order to add role-based authorization you need to add `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` to your Configure method. Instead you are presented with many combinations of Authorization attribute and then at the bottom there is a brief paragraph "Add Role services to Identity" which gives no explanation that this is what makes it all to work.